# Syntax error in bash script that kills application conditioned on GPU temperature

Tags: bash, syntax-error

Why do I get a syntax error on line 8 on executing this script? Setting e.g. i=2 and copying the relevant lines 6 and 8 to the console works fine.

```
#! /bin/bash

# kills MATLAB if a GPU reaches a threshhold temperature
while true
do
    gputemps=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=index,temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)
    for i in 2 4 6 8
        gputemp=$(echo ${gputemps} | awk -v var=$i '{print $var}')
        if [ $gputemp -ge $1 ] 
        then
            killall MATLAB
        fi
   done
   sleep 1m
done
```

Note that the script needs 4 Nvidia GPUs to work properly or at least one if setting i=2 instead of using the for-loop. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

# kills MATLAB if a GPU reaches a threshhold temperature
while true
do
    gputemps=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=index,temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)
    for i in 2 4 6 8
        do
        gputemp=$(echo ${gputemps} | awk -v var=$i '{print $var}')
        if [ $gputemp -ge $1 ] then
            killall MATLAB
        fi
   done
   sleep 1m
done
```

You were missing a `do` for your `for loop`.

Comment: Thank you Farhad. I also removed the else : and now it works (maybe you can edit that too).

Comment: The `else` should be fine; running `:` is equivalent to doing nothing as if there were no `else`.